# How to use in rake task ActiveRecord model and argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

In a rake task I'm using argument like this:

```
namespace :foo do
  task :bar, [:arg1] do |t, args|
    puts args[:arg1]
  end
end
```

And I want to use ActiveRecord model, I add `=> :environment` like this:

```
namespace :foo do
  task :bar => :environment, [:arg1] do |t, args|
    puts args[:arg1]
  end
end
```

And when I run `rake foo:bar[1]`, it ends up with error:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /home/ironsand/rails_project/lib/tasks/foo.rake:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting =>
  task :bar => :environment, [:arg1] do |t, args|
```

What should I to use ActiveRecord model and argument same time in a rake task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
namespace :foo do
  task :bar, [:arg1] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts args[:arg1]
  end
end
```